# Firefox (and only Firefox) can't load some websites when using WiFi, works with LAN

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, firefox

I'm trying to debug this connection issue with some websites (facebook or youtube for example): [www.facebook.com](http://www.facebook.com) loads correctly on Edge o Chrome on my laptop, using wifi OR lan connection, connecting to the same AP Router that connects to my ADSL modem. If I use Firefox, with LAN, works the same, fine. If I use Firefox, over wifi, can't load facebook.com (or youtube.com, or others).

Can't find a reason. There should be no difference between wifi or lan, and there isn't, for Edge and Chrome. But there is, for Firefox. I tried to look for all the possibile settings, but can't find any difference.

How can I debug this? Tried tracert and nslookup of [www.facebook.com](http://www.facebook.com) , with wifi and lan, and are exactly the same, as expected. Erased cache in Firefox (but why?), and tried a Firefox Portable version, for a completely virgin installation, and have the same problem. Firefox version is the latest 92.0.1, but I've been having this issue for months now. I tried to connect to other wifi networks, office, phone hotspot, and always the same behavior. Everything ok with Edge or Chrome, nothing loads with Firefox with certain websites.

What else can I do to debug this issue? Is there some settings in Firefox that can detect the connection type and change its behavior?

UPDATE3:

I tried to route traffic through Fiddler to debug the issue, and discovered that when using Fiddler as a proxy, with wifi, Firefox works fine.

Firefox,Edge,Chrome over LAN, all work (load all sites)
Edge, Chrome over wifi all work, Firefox has problems
Firefox over wifi with Fiddler works

UPDATE2:

I've tested my laptop with another wifi network, and facebook.com (and the other sites not working) works.
So with Firefox I can load Facebook.com on my home lan, my office lan, my office wifi, but NOT my home wifi.
With Edge or Chrome, works in any situation.
I'd really like to debug this issue.

It's not a matter of facebook.com ,I'm using it as an example, many other websites doesn't work.

UPDATE1:

[image: www.facebook.com loaded with Firefox on LAN]

[www.facebook.com](http://www.facebook.com) loaded with Firefox on LAN

[image: www.facebook.com NOT loaded with Firefox on wifi]

[www.facebook.com](http://www.facebook.com) NOT loaded with Firefox on wifi

[image: www.facebook.com loaded with Edge on wifi]

[www.facebook.com](http://www.facebook.com) loaded with Edge on wifi

Comment: What are the proxy options configured in the OS and in Firefox? On Windows, Edge & Chrome will use the system proxy, while Firefox uses its own configuration.

Comment: On Firefox I tried "No Proxy" and "System Proxy settings", doesn't change the result, LAN ok wifi no load.

Comment: Okayo. Is it for all websites or only some of them? What error text do you get, exactly?

Comment: No only some of them. Facebook, Youtube loads partially with no thumbnails, instagram. Other sites, over wifi work perfectly. No error message, just doesn't load, or load partially, with no images. If I use the developer console I see the request and nothing else.

Comment: Any errors are visible in Developer tab (F12)?

Comment: No errors, I've updated the question with screenshots of the developer tab, showing that facebook.com loads fine with FFox on LAN, but not on wifi. But at the same time, on Edge, wifi, works.

Comment: I had a similar issue with Firefox Mobile some weeks ago during vacation in Italy. On WiFi I was unable to connect to any website with Firefox while Chrome worked just fine. Using LTE website access with Firefox worked! The issue was gone without any changes on my mobile but reoccured every now and then. I am very curious to know the reason for this problem.

Comment: I've updated the question with a test on another Wifi network, where FFox works.
It really stumbles me why on my home wifi it doesn't work, but Edge or Chrome does.
I'm trying to understand where to look and how to debug this issue.

Comment: Have you tried deleting the cookies of firefox? Opening site in private Window?

Comment: Yes, I've completely uninstalled and reinstalled Firefox, tried private, and also tried Firefox portable. I'm starting to think it may be a certificate thing... I've read that Firefox is the only browser that uses its own certificates. But why a clean installation fails? And why it works through Fiddler? And at the same time, all other browsers work all the time

Comment: Use a network sniffer like Wireshark to find out what connections are used by Firefox vs. e.g. Edge.

Comment: Done that, I see the connection open to the Facebook ip, port 443, seems correct. Don't know what else to look for.